# How can I evaluate postfix expression in this code?

Tags: c, struct

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct stack
{
    char *oprtr;
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

int stackTop(struct stack* sp){
    return sp->arr[sp->top];
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


void push(struct stack* ptr, char val){
    if(isFull(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Overflow! Cannot push %d to the stack\n", val);
    }
    else{
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}




void push1(struct stack* ptr, char val){
    if(isFull(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Overflow! Cannot push %d to the stack\n", val);
    }
    else{
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->oprtr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}

char pop1(struct stack* ptr){
    if(isEmpty(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Underflow! Cannot pop from the stack\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        char val = ptr->oprtr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return val;
    }
}




char pop(struct stack* ptr){
    if(isEmpty(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Underflow! Cannot pop from the stack\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        char val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return val;
    }
}
int precedence(char ch){
    if(ch == '*' || ch=='/')
        return 3;
    else if(ch == '+' || ch=='-')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isOperator(char ch){
    if(ch=='+' || ch=='-' ||ch=='*' || ch=='/')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
char* infixToPostfix(char* infix){
    struct stack * sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    sp->size = 10;
    sp->top = -1;
    sp->arr = (char *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(char));
    char * postfix = (char *) malloc((strlen(infix)+1) * sizeof(char));
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
    while (infix[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(!isOperator(infix[i])){
            postfix[j] = infix[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            if(precedence(infix[i])> precedence(stackTop(sp))){
                push(sp, infix[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                postfix[j] = pop(sp);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!isEmpty(sp))
    {
        postfix[j] = pop(sp);
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
    return postfix;
}

float evaulate(struct stack *ptr, char *postfix[]){
    float val,val2;
    struct stack *sp;
    int k,a,b,i=0;
    char ch;
   /* sp->top=-1;*/
    while(postfix[i]!='\0'){



        if(isdigit(postfix[i])){

            push1(sp,postfix[i]-'0');

        }
        else if(ch=='+' || ch=='-' || ch=='*' || ch=='/'){

            a=pop1(sp);
            b=pop1(sp);
            k=atoi(postfix[i]);

            switch(k){

            case '*':
                val=b*a;
                break;

            case '+':
                val=b+a;
                break;

            case '-':
                val=b-a;
                break;
            case '/':
                val=b/a;
                break;




            }


            push1(sp,val);


        }

        i++;
    }


    val2=pop1(sp);

    return val2;
}





int main()
{

    char * infix = "20-15/5-3*2";
    char oprnd=infixToPostfix(infix);
    printf("postfix is %s", infixToPostfix(infix));
    struct stack *sp;
    sp->top=-1;

    printf("result is::%d",evaulate(sp,oprnd));
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the evaluate part doesnt work. I do not know why. Can you help me? I trying to convert infix to postfix and then evaulate. The conversion an stack part does not belong to me but I added evaluate part. When I run this code just postfix part outs in console. Maybe the problem variable types but I turn it into float.

Comment: First, `char* infixToPostfix()` returns a pointer to allocated memory, but you have `char oprnd = infixToPostfix(infix);` a single character. Then you pass that single `char` to `float evaulate(struct stack *ptr, char *postfix[])` which is expecting an **array of pointers**. Check out the compiler warnings.

Comment: How can I fix it? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: First, enable full compiler warnings. You need to look at the difference between a `char variable` *integer*, a `char *variable` *pointer*, and a `char *variable[]` *array of pointers*. A review of the chapters in your text book might be needed.

Comment: By the way my friend the compiler does not give any error. Because of that I confused.

Comment: MSVC gives 16 warnings about the code and they all need fixing. Enable all the warnings, if gcc then use `-Wall`.

Comment: What is wall my friend?

Comment: It is the gcc compiler option to report 'All Warnings'.

Comment: My friend I am sorry for bothering you. I tried but it still do not work. Can you help me fix it? I am beginner for programming. Thank you for your answer.